# How do you use "GParted" if you have no unallocated space?

Tags: dual-boot, gparted, unallocated

I'm trying to install Windows 10 alongside Ubuntu, and all the guides I've seen so far assume you have unallocated space.

Comment: You will need to shrink one of your partitions to make space. If you are trying to shrink the same partition that Ubuntu is installed on, you will need to do this with the Live USB/DVD, as you cannot modify partitions that are active.

Comment: By "Live USB/DVD", do you mean being booted into the setup?

Comment: By “Live USB/DVD” I mean the installation media for Ubuntu. You’ll need to boot into a live session using the “Try Ubuntu” option, which loads the OS into RAM. From there you can resize system partitions.

Comment: From my experience, you should only operate on Windows partitions with Windows tools, and Ubuntu partitions with Ubuntu tools.  And backup everything you would care about losing first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to resize your Windows C: drive **from Windows itself**. Doing it from Linux can break the system. Use Disk Management to do this. After that, reboot back to the Ubuntu Live USB/DVD. Make a partition for Ubuntu (ext4).

Or you could just click "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows (Boot Manager)" and install Ubuntu that way.

Comment: This would be helpful, if only I didn't have to overwrite my Windows install due to a slight "User Profile Service" error.